# Bootstrap table footer text alignment issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Facing an issue in text alignment ,footer columns are not in line with table columns, issue screenshot attached below.Tried using pull-right, pull-left but cant resolve.  [Issue Screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iUfU.jpg)

```
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th><?=lang("total");?></th>
                <th class="text-right"><?=$this->sma->formatMoney($inv->total + $inv->product_tax);?></th>
            </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th><?=lang("rounding");?></th>
                    <th class="text-right"><?=$rounding;?></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><?=lang("grand_total");?></th>
                    <th class="text-right"><?=$this->sma->formatMoney($inv->grand_total + $rounding);?></th>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

add `colspan` in last `th`

```
<tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th><?=lang("total");?></th>
                <th class="text-right" colspan="2"><?=$this->sma->formatMoney($inv->total + $inv->product_tax);?></th>
            </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th><?=lang("rounding");?></th>
                    <th class="text-right" colspan="2"><?=$rounding;?></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><?=lang("grand_total");?></th>
                    <th class="text-right" colspan="2"><?=$this->sma->formatMoney($inv->grand_total + $rounding);?></th>
                </tr>
```